# Reduce space between Edit and Remove Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

User click on Mask image & upload image from his computer....

For First mask image, there is no space b/w **Edit and Remove** Text , thats fine....

[image]

**Issue** :

But for 2nd mask image, there is space b/w **Edit and Remove** Text , but i don't want that space....

Codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/WWpEZv

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/9rdwjoce/

**Edit code** :

```
if ($(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).length === 1) {
    $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
        "<span class=\"edit\" >Edit </span>" +
        "</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({
        "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
        "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].height / 2) + "px"
    });
}
```

**Remove code**

```
$("<br/><span id=\"" + newImageLoadedId + "\" class=\"remove\">Remove</span>").insertAfter("#fileup").css({
    "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
    "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].height / 2) + "px"
});
```

**css**

```
.edit {
    display: block;
    background: #444;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

.remove {   
    background: #444;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Below is code snippet :

```js
// Display pop up next to text
function closePopUp(el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
    openID = null
}

function openPopUp(el) {
    ///console.log(" open is called ",id)
    if (openID != null) {
        closePopUp(openID)
    }
    el.style.display = 'block';
    openID = el;
}


let openID = null;


var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
    "path": " newyear collage\/",
    "info": {
        "author": "",
        "keywords": "",
        "file": "newyear collage",
        "date": "sRGB",
        "title": "",
        "description": "Normal",
        "generator": "Export Kit v1.2.8"
    },
    "name": "newyear collage",
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 612,
        "layers": [{
                "x": 0,
                "color": "0xFFFFFF",
                "height": 612,
                "y": 0,
                "width": 612,
                "shapeType": "rectangle",
                "type": "shape",
                "name": "bg_rectangle"
            },
            {
                "x": 160,
                "height": 296,
                "layers": [{
                        "x": 0,
                        "height": 296,
                        "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
                        "y": 0,
                        "width": 429,
                        "type": "image",
                        "name": "mask_image_1"
                    },
                    {
                        "radius": "26 \/ 27",
                        "color": "0xACACAC",
                        "x": 188,
                        "y": 122,
                        "height": 53,
                        "width": 53,
                        "shapeType": "ellipse",
                        "type": "shape",
                        "name": "useradd_ellipse1"
                    }
                ],
                "y": 291,
                "width": 429,
                "type": "group",
                "name": "user_image_1"
            },
            {
                "x": 25,
                "height": 324,
                "layers": [{
                        "x": 0,
                        "height": 324,
                        "src": "hEM2kEP.png",
                        "y": 0,
                        "width": 471,
                        "type": "image",
                        "name": "mask_image_2"
                    },
                    {
                        "radius": "26 \/ 27",
                        "color": "0xACACAC",
                        "x": 209,
                        "y": 136,
                        "height": 53,
                        "width": 53,
                        "shapeType": "ellipse",
                        "type": "shape",
                        "name": "useradd_ellipse_2"
                    }
                ],
                "y": 22,
                "width": 471,
                "type": "group",
                "name": "user_image_2"
            }
        ],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 612,
        "type": "group",
        "name": "newyearcollage08"
    }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // below code will upload image onclick mask image

    $('.container').click(function(e) {
        // filtering out non-canvas clicks
        if (e.target.tagName !== 'CANVAS') return;

        // getting absolute points relative to container
        const absX = e.offsetX + e.target.parentNode.offsetLeft + e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
        const absY = e.offsetY + e.target.parentNode.offsetTop + e.currentTarget.offsetTop;

        const $canvasList = $(this).find('canvas');
        // moving all canvas parents on the same z-index
        $canvasList.parent().css({
            zIndex: 0
        });

        $canvasList.filter(function() { // filtering only applicable canvases
            const bbox = this.getBoundingClientRect();
            const canvasTop = bbox.top + window.scrollY;
            const canvasLeft = bbox.left + window.scrollX;
            return (
                absX >= canvasLeft && absX <= canvasLeft + bbox.width &&
                absY >= canvasTop && absY <= canvasTop + bbox.height)
        }).each(function() { // checking white in a click position
            const x = absX - this.parentNode.offsetLeft - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
            const y = absY - this.parentNode.offsetTop - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;
            const pixel = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                $(this).parent().css({
                    zIndex: 2
                })
                target = this.id;
                console.log(target);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        })
    });

    // Below code will fetch mask images from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

            //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ]
            var ImagePosition = arr;
            //code end

            // Display icon only for mask images

            if (name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1) {
                var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
            } else {
                var imageUrl1 = '';
            }
            //code end

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl1,
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

                //  Edit image

if ($(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).length === 1) {
    $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
        "<span class=\"edit\" >Edit </span>" +
        "</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({
        "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
        "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].height / 2) + "px"
    });
}                
                    // Edit code end here....

                // Edit image code end here....

                //  Remove image

$("<br/><span id=\"" + newImageLoadedId + "\" class=\"remove\">Remove</span>").insertAfter("#fileup").css({
    "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
    "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].height / 2) + "px"
});
    

                $(".remove").click(function(event) {
                    const canvasId = "canvas#" + event.currentTarget.id;
                    // Delete the image
                    const ctx = $("canvas")[event.currentTarget.id].getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle = "white"
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
                    // Delete the button
                    $(this).remove();
                });

                // Remove image code end here.... 
            };
            counter++;
        }
        drawText(data);
    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

function drawText(layer) {

    if (layer.type === 'image') return;

    if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
        return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
    }

    if (layer.type === 'text') {
        const url = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + layer.src;

        if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
            fonts.push(url);
            $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                "}");
        }

        // Below is POP UP Code
        const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
        const lightIdString = '#' + lightId
        $('.container').append(
            '<a id ="' + layer.name + '" onclick="openPopUp(' + lightId + ')"' +
            '<div class="txtContainer" contenteditable="true" ' +
            'style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
            '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>' +
            '<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> content <a href="javascript:void(0)" ' +
            'onclick="closePopUp(' + lightId + ')">Close</a></div> <div>'
        );
        document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 'px'
        // Above is POP UP Code
    }

}
// extempl code end 



// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }


        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

                $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                container.selected(evt);
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                var img = new Image();
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

            }
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {

            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                    if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                        var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                        var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                        if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                            return; // position has not changed
                        settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                        settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                        prevX = evt.clientX;
                        prevY = evt.clientY;
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            container.updateStyle();
                            renderInnerImage();
                        }, 20);
                    }
                } else {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            //if (img)
            // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };


        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        // code end
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: gold;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.txtContainer {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF
}

.txtContainer:hover {
 background: red;
 padding: 1px;
 border-style: dotted;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.remove { 
 background: #444;
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 3;
}

.remove:hover {
 background: white;
 color: black;
}

.edit {
 display: block;
 background: #444;
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 3;
}

.edit:hover {
 background: white;
 color: black;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 3;
}

.white_content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 16px solid orange;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1002;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```

I gave same positions for both Edit and Remove Text....

Comment: Why do you insert delete in the wrong place? Have you tried inspect resulting html?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan thanks for comment, are you telling about `remove(delete)` ? yes, i tried inspecting , but i did't got any idea.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You place Remove button in the wrong place - right after `#fileup`. So you have two remove buttons before your container, having edit buttons inside it. What a mess.

```
$("<br/><span id=\"" + newImageLoadedId + "\" 
class=\"remove\">Remove</span>").insertAfter("#fileup");
```

But Edit button you place after `masked-img` (good way).

```
$("<span class=\"pip\">" +
    "<span class=\"edit\" >Edit </span>" +
    "</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img"
```

Just place them one after the other in separate containers like

```
<div class="buttons-container">
   edit button here 
   remove button here
</div>
```

There is a simple fix. You can just make `position:absolute` to position buttons relative to their containers. And `+25px` for one of them. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbyRLg)

Comment: sorry for the mess, now i placed remove button also after `masked-img` , now remove button is displaying inside container, but still the issue is present , here is updated codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/LvWzwp , can you please tell what code changes i need to do ?

Comment: @vickeycolors try it

Comment: This is great, thanks for your valuable time.... I wish all the best for your business :)